# Adding imageview on UITextField with auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am creating a custom searchbar with `UITextfield`. Searchbar should look like this:
[image]

But, In my case it is appearing like this:
[image]

**What is the mistake I am doing in setting constraints for `imageview` on `textfield`**

**Code:**

```
    UITextField *searchBarTF=[[UITextField alloc]init];


    [searchBarTF setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    searchBarTF.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor darkGrayColor]CGColor];
    searchBarTF.layer.borderWidth=7;
    searchBarTF.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    searchBarTF.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeySearch;

    searchBarTF.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Search by locations" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor grayColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16]}];
    searchBarTF.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    UIImageView *srchBariconImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"srchBarIcon"]];
    [srchBariconImageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [searchBarTF  addSubview:srchBariconImageView];
    [searchBarTF addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:srchBariconImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:searchBarTF attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:40]];
    [searchBarTF addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:srchBariconImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:searchBarTF attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-(views.frame.size.width-80)]];


    [searchBarTF addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:srchBariconImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:40]];
//    
// [searchBarTF addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:srchBariconImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:40]];

     [searchBarTF setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];


     // replace views with self.view.
     [views addSubview:searchBarTF];
     [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBarTF attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:views attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];


    [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBarTF attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:60]];


  //  [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBarTF attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:views attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:-64]];


    [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBarTF attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:views attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];



      [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBarTF attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:views attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:130]];
```

Comment: Your constraints aren't wrong, it's just that you're setting the border radius for the wrong thing.

Comment: You could put this together in interface builder in like 5 min.

Comment: I am not worry about border and all. What i need is the searchbar icon in my textfield. @ILikeTau

Comment: add leftview image in textfield.

Comment: Nothing is happening. @johnykumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Subclass UITextField and overwrite these methods     
- (void)awakeFromNib{
    CGRect frame =    self.leftView.frame;
    frame.size.width = 30;
    frame.size.height = 30;
    self.leftView.frame = frame;
    self.leftView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"underfloor_cross_blue.png"]];
}

- (CGRect)leftViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds{
    CGRect rect=CGRectMake(8, 8,50.0, 45);
    [super leftViewRectForBounds:rect];
    return rect ;
}
```

Note: change image and frame according to your need.

Comment: It worked. I will use your code. But, still searching for my answer related to auto layout. Why is this custom imageview not coming when I am using auto layout.

Comment: let me implement it with autolayout and will update my answer soon.